# Customising y-labels on a secondary y-axis in matplotlib to format to thousands with a comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, formatting, subplot

I am having difficulty formatting the tick labels on a secondary y-axis in matplotlib, I would like to have the secondary y-axis labels formatted to include commas to separate out the thousands (e.g 20,000 instead of 20000). When working with a singular y-axis I normally just use:

```
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

which works exactly the way I intend it to. However, whenever I try and do the same thing on a plot with a secondary y-axis this just doesn't work, it does nothing at all actually.

Example (the numbers/context are meaningless, its just to show a minimal working example):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib as mpl, numpy as np

y = [k for k in range(240)]

def CtoF(x):
    return (x * 1.8 + 32) + 10000


def FtoC(x):
    return (x - 32) / 1.8

temperature = np.random.randn(len(y))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(10,5))

ax.plot(y, temperature)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$T\ [^oC]$')

secaxy = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(CtoF, FtoC))
secaxy.set_ylabel(r'$T\ [^oF]$ + 10000')
secaxy.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

plt.show()
```

The above code does not change the labels on the secondary y-axis as it normally does when it is applied to a plot with just a singular y-axis, it does nothing at all and just leaves the labels the same.

Some other things I have tried that also do not work are getting the yticks separately and then manually setting the labels as follows:

```
vals = secaxy.get_yticks()
secaxy.set_yticklabels(['{:,}'.format(x) for x in vals])
```

this also does nothing to the secondary y-axis labels.

I would appreciate any help on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install matplotlib==3.2.1
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I am already currently running matplotlib version 3.2.1, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling also, this still does not resolve the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue in that case. Y axis plotting with comma separator values for me.

Comment: Upon deleting previous versions of matplotlib and reinstalling the latest version as you suggested I can confirm that this does indeed solve the problem and the secondary axis ticks labels are appearing as they should be. Strange that it never worked on the previous version though, nonetheless - thank you!